# Ubuntu Shows A Blank Screen During Startup Instead Of The Ubuntu Logo

Tags: boot, grub2, startup, plymouth, restart

I'm kind of new to Ubuntu and linux in general. After the grub screen the ubuntu logo shows up for less then a second and then eveything turns black for about 30 seconds and then I get the login screen. From there on everything works fine, but the ubuntu logo not showing is really bugging me. I searched for it a lot online and some guy said to install plymouth themes, so I did.
And select an alernative ubuntu logo theme.
By using this command

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

And said that I check the current theme without restarting with this command

```
sudo plymouthd ; sudo plymouth --show-splash ; for ((I=0; I<10; I++)); do sleep 1 ; sudo plymouth --update=test$I ; done ; sudo plymouth --quit
```

This command properly shows the ubuntu logo but while the actual startup it doesn't load.

How can I get the good old ubuntu logo back?

Any Help Would Be Appreciated!